# Access Linux kernel crypto API from Docker

Tags: linux, docker, cryptography

I'm using Linux crypto API with the help of [libkcapi](https://github.com/smuellerDD/libkcapi). My code seems to work fine when run under my normal user account. However it fails if executed in a Docker container. E.g.

```
libkcapi - Error: Netlink error: sendmsg failed
libkcapi - Error: Netlink error: sendmsg failed
libkcapi - Error: NETLINK_CRYPTO: cannot obtain cipher information for stdrng (is required crypto_user.c patch missing? see documentation)
```

Both host and container run Debian 10 (buster), though this shouldn't matter as the container uses the host kernel anyway.

I tried many security-relaxing Docker options without success:

- --privileged
- --cap-add ALL
- --security-opt seccomp=unconfined
- --security-opt apparmor=unconfined
- --security-opt label=disable

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Do you have any update?